# How to do complex conditional filtering in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I want to filter an array of objects according to a few filters I have created:

```js
items.filter(
    (obj) =>
    (!status || (obj.globalId && obj.globalId !== "")) &&
    (!deletedSwitch || obj.deleted === deletedSwitch) &&
    (!filteredUsername || obj.userId === userId) &&
    (!filteredType || obj.type === filteredType) &&
    (!filteredVariety || obj.variety === filteredVariety) &&
    (!filteredSize || parseInt(obj.size) === filteredSize)
)
```

So as you can see, I filter the items based on a few properties. These properties are selected through a `<select>` component. `status` property used to be a `boolean` state where I want to check if the item has a `globalId` or not. However, now I want to change it in a way where I check if `status` is `connected`, then I want to filter all items that have a `globalId` each. But if the `status` is `not connected`, I want to filter all items that DO NOT have a `globalId`. How can I modify my code above to achieve this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it with OR?

```js
items.filter(obj =>
    ((status === "connected" && obj.globalId && obj.globalId !== "") ||
     (status === "not connected" && !obj.globalId)) &&
    (!deletedSwitch || obj.deleted === deletedSwitch) &&
    (!filteredUsername || obj.userId === userId) &&
    (!filteredType || obj.type === filteredType) &&
    (!filteredVariety || obj.variety === filteredVariety) &&
    (!filteredSize || parseInt(obj.size) === filteredSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a ternary (conditional expression)?

```
(status == "connected" ?
 object.globalId && obj.globalId !== "" :
 !object.globalId)
```

Or, if you anticipate having more `status` values in the future, using an object is more extensible (and it's arguably more readable in any case):

```
({
    "connected": object.globalId && obj.globalId !== "",
    "not connected": !object.globalId,
}[status])
```